# "system objects" vs. "server objects" in SQL Server - terms definitions?

Tags: sql-server, terminology

What are the definitions of "system object" and of "server object" in SQL Server?

Is Server object also system one? And vice versa?

And what are the differences between "system" and "server' objects in SQL Server?

What's distinguishing them?

Update:

There is a node in Object Explorer of SSMS for Server Objects (I have now only 2008 R2).

SSMS menu Options --> Environment --> General --> "Hide system objects in Object Explorer" checkbox

Hide system databases but not Server objects.

One can google for these terms. They are broadly used but not defined

Answer (score 3):

"System objects" are the SQL server internal databases / tables / views etc. which SQL server requires to function. Examples would be the master, model and msdb databases, or database level objects in the `sys` schema. You might elect to hide them just to keep them out of the way in the object explorer.

"Server Objects" are user-defined objects defined at server level - backup devices, linked servers and so on.

Comment: +1 excellent answer. System objects would also include the DMV (dynamic mgmt views).