# storage location of server objects in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, configuration, memory-management, terminology

Subquestioning [1] and [2].
Where does SQL Server store server objects?

And why there?

Update:
This question is defined as subquestion and in context of cited questions...

Should I understand the answer that sql_policy_trigger, shown under Server Objects\Triggers in Object Explorer of SSMS (MS SQL Server R2), is stored in master database?

---

**=====Update2:**
Please give me the references to msdn docs in your answer(s).

It is not obvious that system or server configuration objects, meta-information or catalogs are stored in database(s). For ex., FTS catalog is not stored in database but in file (system), etc.

[3] (BOL2005-2008R2) tells that:

- "master Database

  Records all the system-level information for an instance of SQL Server"

  - "In SQL Server, system objects are no longer stored in the master database; **instead, they are stored in the Resource database**"

So, it is  instance-wide (but not server-wide) and it clearly mentions "system".
As well as it hints that "they" are not stored in master database.

Also, I would like to understand why SSMS permits to script server objects (for ex., right-click in Object Explorer under Server Objects --> Triggers on  syspolicy_server_trigger --> Script Server Trigger as...---> ) while, for ex., system views do not have such possibility.

---

**Cited:**
[1]
Where does a Server trigger save in SQL Server ?
[Where does a Server trigger save in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843256/where-does-a-server-trigger-save-in-sql-server)
[2]
“system objects” vs. “server objects” in SQL Server - terms definitions?
["system objects" vs. "server objects" in SQL Server - terms definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845035/system-objects-vs-server-objects-in-sql-server-terms-definitions)
[3]
master Database
[3a]
(SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx
[3b]
(SQL Server 2005 Books Online)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 4):

sys.objects, sys.indexes etc (as per your trigger question). See [Object catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx) in MSDN

As for why, a relational database may as well use a relation structure to store information about itself, no? Apart from a few registry settings used on start up, almost ***every*** setting and object is [stored in a table somewhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) in SQL Server.

Examples:

- [sys.messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187382.aspx) = error messages
- [sys.configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188345.aspx) = sp_configure

Edit, I had to dredge my memory about why this is so...

[Rule zero in Codd's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules)

> The system must qualify as
>   relational, as a database, and as a
>   management system. For a system to
>   qualify as a relational database
>   management system (RDBMS), that system
>   must use its relational facilities
>   (exclusively) to manage the database.

This ignores the "relational" puritans and zealots but explains why sys.objects etc are used.

Edit:

Making a guess at what OP really wants... server level objects are stored in the master database.

Comment: It looks to me like you referenced views and database-wide (or database specific) ones  while I asked about storage location of objects and server-wide ones.

Comment: Did you not read my answer or any of the links? There are catalog for *all* objects (sys.server_principals, sys.configurations etc). Otherwise, please clarify your question so we can answer what you really want to know. Don't criticise those who try to answer vague, ill-defined questions.